# Tutorials about the Silverlight Navigation Application template?

Tags: templates, silverlight-3.0

Silverlight's Navigation Application template seems promising, however, I can't seem to find any tutorials (particularly video tutorials).  Whatever I did find was from the beta and is inconsistent with the released version.

Has anyone seen any non-beta tutorials (particularly video)?